# Erro ao importar módulo em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo um problema ao importar um modulo em JavaScript. Estou utilizando um servidor HTTPS em Python para criar meus sites.

Arquivo: `modules/index.js`:

```
export function soma (c,d){
    return c + d
}
```

Arquivo `index.js`:

```
import {soma} from "./modules/index"

let value = soma(3,5)

console.log(value)
```

Quando vou no console, aparece este erro:

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Como posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: A sua function de soma está errada!

Answer (score 4):

Assumindo que seu *index.js* está sendo importado em uma tag `script`, creio que o erro seja por faltar a especificação do tipo *MIME* do arquivo que você está tentando importar.

Nesse caso, tente fazer a importação informando a extensão do arquivo `.js` no seu *index.js*:

```
//                                    ↓↓ informe a extensão
import { soma } from "./modules/index.js";

let value = soma(3, 5); // 5 

console.log(value);
```

> Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Para não receber esse erro, é obrigatório informar a extensão do arquivo `.js` para scripts do tipo `type="module"`.

Com a excelente ajuda @AugustoVasques que nos forneceu um bom [link para consulta](https://v8.dev/features/modules#mjs), alguns pontos tem que ser levados em conta:

> *a preferência é que módulos receberem a extensão .mjs pois na fase de projeto lints olham essa extensão e tratam o arquivo adequadamente e interpretadores standalone procuram preferencialmente por essa extensão.*

Nesse caso, para tag script com `type="module"`, é melhor reescrevermos a extensão do arquivo para o tipo *module*. Neste caso, vamos mudar de `.js` para `.mjs` no código:

```
//                                    ↓↓↓ informe a extensão .mjs
import { soma } from "./modules/index.mjs";

let value = soma(3, 5); // 5 

console.log(value);
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques Boa informação, vale a pena editar a reposta e acrescentar esse extra.

Comment: Se pudesse dava outro +1